# How to deal the error when compile the hadoop2.7.3?

Tags: maven, hadoop

The software  I used as following:
[image: the version]

And I meet the error as following:
[image: The error I meet]

The system I used is Centos 7 and the JDK I used is 1.7.0_07. Anyone can help me to solve the problem?

Comment: As i see,Maven is searching `pom.xml` in `/usr/local/bigdata/softwares/hadoop-2.7.3-src`. Can you try the same command within the specified path!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your system can't resolve repo.maven.apache.org. There might be a problem with DNS or internet connection on that machine.